# Suggested method for fast reverse lookup by value in key/value pairs in C++

Tags: c++, qt

I need to have a large key/value pair array in C++ memory that might look something like the following.  However, the real world example will be tens of thousands of records:

```
key    value
-----  -----
1      20
2      20
3      12
4      3
5      blank
6      3
7      blank
...
```

Given a value of '3', I need a fast reverse lookup of matching keys (4 & 6 in this example).  I would like to avoid iterating the list.  Is there a recommended solution in C++?

I would prefer to use the Qt library.  I have looked at QMap and QHash, but a fast reverse lookup doesn't seem an option?

Comment: Can you be explicit about what the requirements are in this question?  Preferring some libraries and dismissing others as they're offered makes this a more chatty, open-ended question.  Are you saying that the solution needs to use Qt?

Comment: Have you benchmarked? A vector of pairs or two vectors can be orders of magnitudes faster than hashes/maps, which are way more sparse in memory.

Comment: I am looking into the boost.bimap solution and will update shortly

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Is there a recommended solution in C++?

If Boost can be an option (I know you prefer Qt). Then you can use [`Boost.Bimap`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_57_0/libs/bimap/doc/html/index.html#bimap.preface)

> Boost.Bimap is a bidirectional maps library for C++. With Boost.Bimap
>   you can create associative containers in which both types can be used
>   as key. A bimap can be thought of as a combination of a
>   std::map and a std::map. The learning curve of bimap is
>   almost flat if you know how to use standard containers. A great deal
>   of effort has been put into mapping the naming scheme of the STL in
>   Boost.Bimap. The library is designed to match the common STL
>   containers.

Otherwise, since Qt has not a suitable data-structure. You can use two maps, to achieve your goal. However, it duplicates memory.

Comment: Good idea, but Boost is not an option in my case :(

Answer (score 3):

What you're looking for is bidirectional map concept. Sadly, Qt does not provide a readily available solution for this.

If you're looking to use only Qt libraries, you'll have to maintain two `QMap`s (or `QHash`es or something equivalent).

```
QMap<int, QPair<int,bool> > forwardLookupMap
QMap<QPair<int, bool>, int> reverseLookupMap
```

You would have to maintain reverse lookup map by hand, which is cumbersome, and memory requirements don't look too good.

Alternative option would be using third-party implementation, like [Boost.Bimap](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_58_0/libs/bimap/doc/html/index.html)